# Exit from Apache Camel loop

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, apache-servicemix

I want to exit from Camel Loop at some condition. I am using Camel 2.15

```
 .loop(simple("${exchangeProperty.loopCount}"))
   .to("bean:xxx?method=exitFromLoop")
 .end()
```

I tried changing CamelLoopIndex and CamelLoopSize in exitFromLoop method, but didn't worked for me.

Is there any alternative to this e.g using choice/when?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a loop while mode if you use Camel 2.17 onwards.

See the documentation: http://camel.apache.org/loop

Then the loop runs like a while loop until the predicate evaluates to false / null or zero.

As its a predicate it does not automatic decrement a counter, so its like a while loop in java.

Comment: Great. Thanks Claus. i am using Fuse 6.2, it use Camel 2.15. Is there any alternative in Camel 2.15?

Comment: You can use dynamic router EIP instead - Or if you do not need to do any more routing after the loop you can mark the exchange to stop

Answer (score 0):

Up to camel 2.16 (and in 2.17 as well) you can use a <camel:stop/> statement in a <camel:when> block inside the <camel:loop>, and set the loop counter to some arbitrary upper limit.

Alternatively your loop may contain a java processor that can conditionally stop the route with:  exchange.setProperty(Exchange.ROUTE_STOP, Boolean.TRUE);